# datepicker is not picking custom date format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Requirement is to display date in the format "22 Jan 2010".

I have coded

```
 calanderFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
 calanderFrom.CustomFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
```

but date is still coming in "5/5/2011" format. Please guide me how to change fromat.

thanks

Comment: Is it displaying that way on the form, or is it returning in that format to your code?

Comment: You could capture the date as it is and format later. This is how I do it. But not sure why its not working in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace

```
calanderFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
```

with

```
 calanderFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Comment: +1 You are right buddy. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Don't kick yourself:

```
calanderFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Use the `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` value instead of `DateTimePickerFormat.Short`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Format to  **System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom**

Change your code to:

```
calanderFrom.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
 calanderFrom.CustomFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RFC1123 pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123). `String.Format("{0:r}", dt);`

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

**Specifier**   **DateTimeFormatInfo property**     **Pattern value (for en-US culture)**

```
t   ShortTimePattern    h:mm tt
d   ShortDatePattern    M/d/yyyy
T   LongTimePattern     h:mm:ss tt
D   LongDatePattern     dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
f   (combination of D and t)    dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
F   FullDateTimePattern     dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
g   (combination of d and t)    M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
G   (combination of d and T)    M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
m, M    MonthDayPattern     MMMM dd
y, Y    YearMonthPattern    MMMM, yyyy
r, R    RFC1123Pattern  ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (*)
s   SortableDateTi­mePattern    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss (*)
u   UniversalSorta­bleDateTimePat­tern  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' (*)
```

Comment: This is not that relevant to the question. Custom format string seems to be configured correctly, the only problem is that `DateTimePickerFormat.Short` is used instead of the custom string (because it's not set to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`).

Comment: But he could change it with *String.Format*. RFC1123Pattern is for that.

Comment: *Requirement is to display date in the format "22 Jan 2010"*.

Comment: @Groo *String.Format("{0:r}", dt);* doesn't do that?

Comment: No, it formats the DateTime as `"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"`, invariant of the current culture (as specified in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123) you provided). RFC1123Pattern is just a standard like any other. I don't see why you think it's supposed to solve anything. Any other date pattern will work, provided that `Format` property is set to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`. But OP explicitly asked for `"dd MMM yyyy"`.